# Pausar audio en segundo plano (al minimizar la aplicación)

Tags: android, audio

Este es mi MainActivity

```
private MediaPlayer mp, mp_presionarbotonverrespuesta;

int num_aleatorio = (int) (Math.random() * 21);


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    et_nombre = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_nombre);
    iv_personaje = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagView_personaje);
    tv_BestScore = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_BestScore);

    AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this, "BD", null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase BD = admin.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor consulta = BD.rawQuery(
             "select * from puntaje where score = (select max(score) from puntaje)", null);
    if (consulta.moveToFirst()){
        String temp_nombre = consulta.getString(0);
        String temp_score =  consulta.getString(1);
        tv_BestScore.setText("Record: " + temp_score + " de  " + temp_nombre);
        BD.close();

    } else {
        BD.close();
    }


    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.futurama_intro);
    mp_presionarbotonverrespuesta = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.presionarbotonverrespuesta);
    mp.start();
    mp.setLooping(true);
}
```

Este es audio que se sigue ejecutando en segundo plano `("R.raw.futurama_intro")`

```
public void Jugar (View view){
    String nombre = et_nombre.getText().toString();

    if (!nombre.equals("")){
        mp_presionarbotonverrespuesta.start();
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();


        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity_Nivel1.class);

        intent.putExtra("jugador", nombre);

        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Primero debes escribir tu nombre", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        et_nombre.requestFocus();
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(this.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(et_nombre, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);

    }

}
```

Pasa que cuando la aplicación se minimiza (al presionar el botón home del celular) o cuando se pone el multitarea el audio de fondo del main activity sigue sonando.

No encuentro como hacer que el audio `(mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.futurama_intro);)` se pause cuando minimice la aplicación

Comment: Entiendo que tendrás que sobreescribir la función de tu `Activity` que se ejecuta cuando se va a segundo plano y ahí ejecutar el `pause` del `MediaPlayer`. Te recomiendo que revises el ciclo de vida de una `Activity` para saber qué funciones tienes que sobreescribir.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando el activity se deje de mostrar el ciclo de vida ejecutara el onPause y cuando vuelva a verse el activity se ejecutara el onResume. Sabiendo esto solo basta detener e iniciar la musica cada vez que se ejecute el onPause y onResume.

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mp.pause();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mp.start();
}
```